# email php message code

Tags: html, css, email, message

I'm trying to send an email in PHP and I'm adding PHP code in the message but it always throws an error when I call the PHP file in Chrome, for example:

```
mail('mail@mail.com', 'subject', 'echo "<br><br><u></u><div style=\"margin:0;padding:0\" dir=\"ltr\">\n"; 
echo "<table style=\"border-collapse:collapse;width:98%\" border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\"><tbody><tr><td style=\"font-family:'lucida grande',tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;font-size:12px\"><table style=\"border-collapse:collapse;width:620px\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">\n"; ', 'From: support@expert.com')
```

I only left a portion of the code, I hope it's enough to get the message across, when I placed the message by itself in a PHP tag, it works and renders the code on the page, but when I entered it in a message it starts causing errors, obviously I'm doing something wrong... please help!!

Comment: **What does the error say**?

Comment: You need to send you message body as a html string and not use `echo` statements.

Comment: That's not how strings work.

Comment: The HTML in your string is basically a soup. I suggest you do some research in how to set up a correct format for html mail.
A good example can be found here: http://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$to = 'mail@mail.com';

$subject = 'Website Change Reqest';

$headers = "From:email@email.com " ."\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";


$message = '<html><body>';

$message .= '<table style="border-collapse:collapse;width:98%" border="0"                   cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">';
$message .= '<tbody><tr><td style="font-family:'lucida grande',tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;font-size:12px">';
$message .= '<table style="border-collapse:collapse;width:620px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">';
$message .= '<tr><td>row 1, cell 1</td><td>row 1, cell 2</td></tr>';
$message .= '<tr><td>row 2, cell 1</td><td>row 2, cell 2</td></tr>';
$message .= '</table>';
$message .= '</body></html>';



mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

?>
```

I've tested this out both this way and using simple html code, the simple html worked, but the second I start adding the html I want, it throws errors.. I'm more comfortable with html and css and java, but this is the first time i'm trying out php, and I have no idea why my html is throwing errors, I'm thinking that maybe its the format of my html for example ...

BTW thanks for the responses...

Comment: Why do you answer your own question when it seems that you have not found a good solution?